# sumif for previous week

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I tried SUMIF formula to calculate data for Previous week only but it seems to be incorrect since the below formula excludes previous day. Help me out.

=SUMIFS(AK:AK,T:T,(">="&WORKDAY(TODAY(),-5)))

Comment: The formula works as expected. If Today is Tuesday, 13th June, then the formula will sum up everything greater than and including Tuesday, 6th June. Edit your question, post a data sample and explain what you would like to see as the result and why.

Comment: True But i need the last week to be stable that i should only calculate from 5th June till 9th June even if I apply formula on 15th June

Comment: In that case you can't use the Workday() function, because it does not do what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to sum all days from the Monday of the past week onwards, try

```
=SUMIFS(AK:AK,T:T,">="&DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()) + 2-WEEKDAY(TODAY()))-7)
```